# MongoDB normalization, foreign key and joining

Tags: mongodb, foreign-keys, normalization, database, nosql

Before I dive really deep into MongoDB for days, I thought I'd ask a pretty basic question as to whether I should dive into it at all or not. I have basically no experience with nosql.

I did read a little about some of the benefits of document databases, and I think for this new application, they will be really great. It is always a hassle to do favourites, comments, etc. for many types of objects (lots of m-to-m relationships) and subclasses - it's kind of a pain to deal with.

I also have a structure that will be a pain to define in SQL because it's extremely nested and translates to a document a lot better than 15 different tables.

But I am confused about a few things.

1. Is it desirable to keep your database normalized still? I really don't want to be updating multiple records. Is that still how people approach the design of the database in MongoDB?
2. What happens when a user favourites a book and this selection is still stored in a user document, but then the book is deleted? How does the relationship get detached without foreign keys? Am I manually responsible for deleting all of the links myself?
3. What happens if a user favourited a book that no longer exists and I query it (some kind of join)? Do I have to do any fault-tolerance here?

Comment: When you do SQL databases like MySQL, they don't delete links between tables automatically, even when connected by foreign key. The only thing they do is stop you from deleting a row in another table connected by foreign key, but even there it is only if you tell it to. Why would you think it would be any different in NoSQL?

Comment: @trysis, google ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: Yeah, I forget why I said that, it was so long ago. I apologize if I misled anyone with my past ignorance.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support server side foreign key relationships, normalization is also discouraged. You should embed your child object within parent objects if possible, this will increase performance and make foreign keys totally unnecessary. That said it is not always possible, so there is a special construct called DBRef which allows to reference objects in a different collection. This may be then not so speedy because DB has to make additional queries to read objects but allows for kind of foreign key reference.

Still you will have to handle your references manually. Only while looking up your DBRef you will see if it exists, the DB will not go through all the documents to look for the references and remove them if the target of the reference doesn't exist any more. But I think removing all the references after deleting the book would require a single query per collection, no more, so not that difficult really.

If your schema is more complex then probably you should choose a relational database and not nosql.

There is also a book about designing MongoDB databases: [Document Design for MongoDB](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018391/)

**UPDATE** The book above is not available anymore, yet because of popularity of MongoDB there are quite a lot of others. I won't link them all, since such links are likely to change, a simple search on Amazon shows multiple pages so it shouldn't be a problem to find some.

See the MongoDB manual page for ['Manual references' and DBRefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) for further specifics and examples

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I actually think this project is big enough that a Relational db is the best option now. In this application, there are going to be a lot of references and it's going to take multiple queries in many cases. It's not worth it.

Comment: The book mentioned in the post is no longer available on Amazon. Do you know if this book has been replaced by another one?

Comment: Found this one : http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920001096.do it probably contain useful information, in case it is not the same book reedited.

Comment: No it's not: the book I've mentioned was written by Jeremy McAnally and Ryan Nitz wherease yours by Kristina Chodorow. Actually MongoDB got quite a big momentum since then and there are plenty of books available, O'Reilly alone has 6, a simple search on Amazon shows multiple pages, a comfortable situation for those that still can read on paper :-)..

Answer (score 27):

Above, @TomaaszStanczak states

> MongoDB doesn't support server side foreign key relationships,
>   normalization is also discouraged. You should embed your child object
>   within parent objects if possible, this will increase performance and
>   make foreign keys totally unnecessary. That said it is not always
>   possible ...

Normalization is not discouraged by Mongo. To be clear, we are talking about two fundamentally different types of relationships two data entities can have. In one, one child entity is *owned* exclusively by a parent object. In this type of relationship the Mongo way is to embed.

In the other class of relationship two entities exist independently - have independent lifetimes and relationships. Mongo wishes that this type of relationship did not exist, and is frustratingly silent on precisely how to deal with it. Embedding is just not a solution. Normalization is not discouraged, or encouraged. Mongo just gives you two mechanisms to deal with it; [Manual refs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) (analoguous to a key with the foreign key constraint binding two tables), and  [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) (a different, slightly more structured way of doing the same). In this use case SQL databases win.

Comment: +1 Agreed.  Quotes on the internet like "Generally speaking, in MongoDB, you'd want to store the data in the way application would access it, thus eliminating the need for joins" are common, but your point on exclusive ownership and the inferred stability of the data is often overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

The answers of both Tomasz and Francis contain good advice: that "normalization" is not discouraged by Mongo, but that you should first consider optimizing your database document design before creating "document references".  `DBRefs` were mentioned by Tomasz, however as he alluded, are not a "magic bullet" and require additional processing to be useful.

What is now possible, as of MongoDB version 3.2, is to produce results equivalent to an SQL *JOIN* by using the **$lookup** aggregation pipeline stage operator.  In this manner you can have a "normalized" document structure, but still be able to produce consolidated results. In order for this to work you need to create a unique key in the target collection that is hopefully both *meaningful* and *unique*.  You can enforce uniqueness by creating a unique index on this field.

**$lookup** usage is pretty straightforward.  Have a look at the documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-aggregation. Run the `aggregate()` method on the source collection (i.e. the "left" table).  The *from* parameter is the target collection (i.e. the "right" table).  The *localField* parameter would be the field in the source collection (i.e. the "foreign key").  The *foreignField* parameter would be the matching field in the target collection.

As far as orphaned documents, from your question I would presume you are thinking about a traditional RDBMS set of constraints, cascading deletes, etc. Again, as of MongoDB version 3.2, there is native support for *document validation*.  Have a look at this StackOver article: [How to apply constraints in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550210/how-to-apply-constraints-in-mongodb)  Look at the second answer, from JohnnyHK

Packt Publishers have a bunch of good books on MongoDB.  (Full Disclosure: I wrote a couple of them.)