# Foreign key like relationship in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

How can I implement a foreign key like relationship in Mongo DB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hiya see this: [MongoDB normalization, foreign key and joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841681/mongodb-normalization-foreign-key-and-joining-question) && further <s>http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018391.do</s> ===> http://books.google.com/books/about/Document_Design_for_MongoDB.html?id=TbIHkgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y

> MongoDB doesn't support server side foreign key relationships,
>   normalization is also discouraged. You should embed your child object
>   within parent objects if possible, this will increase performance and
>   make foreign keys totally unnecessary. That said it is not always
>   possible, so there is a special construct called DBRef which allows to
>   reference objects in a different collection. This may be then not so
>   speedy because DB has to make additional queries to read objects but
>   allows for kind of foreign key reference.
>
> Still you will have to handle your references manually. Only while
>   looking up your DBRef you will see if it exists, the DB will not go
>   through all the documents to look for the references and remove them
>   if the target of the reference doesn't exist any more. But I think
>   removing all the references after deleting the book would require a
>   single query per collection, no more, so not that difficult really.

**Edit update**

http://levycarneiro.com/tag/mongodb/

levycarneiro.com/tag/mongodb [quote] So you create 4 collections: Clients, Suppliers, Employees and Contacts. You connect them all together via a db reference. This acts like a foreign key. But, this is not the mongoDB way to do things. Performance will penalized. [unquote]

Comment: Interesting.  What does it mean by "embed child objects in the parent object"?  Does that mean if you have an order / line-items relationship, you would add line-item objects as properties in the order document?

Comment: Hiya, Indeed,I reckon; interesting article here - http://levycarneiro.com/tag/mongodb/ [quote] So you create 4 collections: Clients, Suppliers, Employees and Contacts. You connect them all together via a db reference. This acts like a foreign key. But, this is not the mongoDB way to do things. Performance will penalized. [unquote] - :) cheers

Comment: Great, it's really helpful Tats. Actually Mongo DB is not that much efficient for implementing references among objects, as I understood.

Comment: @LasanthaBandara: yes, value of references in MongoDB is heavily discounted, because there are no joins.

Comment: Just an FYI - the link to the article is dead.

Comment: @itsmatt thanks bruvo! new link updated or see here: http://books.google.co.nz/books/about/Document_Design_for_MongoDB.html?id=TbIHkgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y `:)`