# How to apply constraints in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have started using MongoDB and I am fairly new to it.
Is there any way by which I can apply constraints on documents in MongoDB?
Like specifying a primary key or taking an attribute as unique?
Or specifying that a particular attribute is greater than a minimum value?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Being a "schemaless" database, some of the things you mention must be constrained from the application side, rather than the db side. (such as "minimum value")

However, you can create indexes (keys to query on--remember that a query can only use one index at a time, so it's generally better to design your indexes around your queries, rather than just index each field you might query against):
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-Basics

And you can also create unique indexes, which will enforce uniqueness similar to a unique constraint (it does have some caveats, such as with array fields):
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-unique%3Atrue

Answer (score 56):

**MongoDB 3.2 Update**

Document validation is now supported natively by MongoDB.

Example from the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document-validation/):

```js
db.createCollection( "contacts",
   { validator: { $or:
      [
         { phone: { $type: "string" } },
         { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
         { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
      ]
   }
} )
```

---

**Original answer**

To go beyond the uniqueness constraint available natively in indexes, you need to use something like [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) and its ability to support field-based [validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).  That will give you support for things like minimum value, but only when updates go through your Mongoose schemas/models.

Comment: It should be mentioned that according to the link users can bypass this validation. Nevertheless a great tool to have.

Comment: should this be $and rather than $or ?