# Unique Constraint with Two Fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with fields "email" and "friends_email". I would like to setup a unique-ness constraint like the following, using MongoDB:

1. No record will have the same value for email and friends_email. So this would be invalid:

   ```
   {"email": "abc@example.com", "friends_email": "abc@example.com" }
   ```
2. No 2 records will have the same values for all fields. So the following examples would ALL be invalid:

   ```
   {
       { "email": "abc@example.com", "friends_email": "def@example.com" },
       { "email": "abc@example.com", "friends_email": "def@example.com" }
   }
   {
       { "email": "abc@example.com", "friends_email": null },
       { "email": "abc@example.com", "friends_email": null }
   }
   {
       { "email": null, "friends_email": "abc@example.com" },
       { "email": null, "friends_email": "abc@example.com" }
   }
   ```

   In plain english, it would be something like, the concatenation of `email` and `friends_email` will be unique, with `null` and `undefined` being coalesced into empty-string.

What's the best way to enforce this rule in MongoDB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have compound unique index on `email` and `friends_email` field for ensuring the second case. But for the first case you need to handle that in the application code or use a java mapper such as Morphia to have a field-based validation. You might wanna check the following post also:

> [How to apply constraints in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550210/how-to-apply-constraints-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 64):

It sounds like you need a compound unique index:

```
db.users.createIndex( { "email": 1, "friends_email": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

... and you can verify at the ORM layer that email =/= friends_email.

Comment: Just a quick update on this: db.collection.ensureIndex(keys, options) is deprecated since version 3.0.0: > db.collection.ensureIndex() is now an alias for db.collection.createIndex().

Answer (score 8):

for the second case, is a unique compound index what you're looking for?

```
 db.emails.ensureIndex( {email:1, friends_email:1}, { unique: true } )
```

As for the first case, I am not sure if there is a way to enforce the first rule.  You may need to perform the check on the application side.

Answer (score 1):

For #1 you can set up checks on the database side using [Schema Validaiton](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/):

```
validator: {
  "$expr": {
    "$ne": [ "$email", "$friends_email" ]
  }
}

db.runCommand( { collMod: "collectionName", validator: validator} )
```