# How to apply inter-collection constraints in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Since MongoDB 3.2 you can set *intra-collection* constrains, as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550210/how-to-apply-constraints-in-mongodb).

However, what avour *inter-collection* constraints (such a the typical foreign key constrain in relational databases to ensure a linked document exists)? Has been something like that being included in recents versions of MongoDB? Is there any plan to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of any functionality like that in MongoDB server.

There is [schema validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) but it also applies only within one collection at a time.

If you use an ODM, some of this may be provided by the ODM. For example, Mongoid offers [dependency constraints](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#dependent-behavior).